# Flask view can't access model class even through it's defined in the same file

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple single file app to test using SQLAlchemy with Flask.  The `getResult` view uses the `MainResult` model.  However, navigating to `/getResult` raise `NameError: global name 'MainResult' is not defined`.  That class is defined in the same file as the view, so why do I get that error?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/testDB'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/getResult')
def getResult():
    newEntry = MainResult(metadata_key='test')
    db.session.add(newEntry)
    db.session.commit()
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

class MainResult(db.Model):
    metadata_key = db.Column(db.String(128), primary_key=True)
```

Comment: move `MainResult` to the top or above where it is called

Answer (score 0):

Python executes files sequentially.  `app.run` runs forever.  So anything after `app.run` in the file will not have been executed and won't be until the server stops.  `MainResult` isn't defined until after the app is run, so the view can't see it.  Move it above the `__main__` block.

```
class MainResult(db.Model):
    ...

# should be the last thing in the file
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Preferably, use the new `flask` command to run the dev server instead.  The `__main__` block is no longer required in this case.

```
FLASK_APP=my_file.py flask run
```